# Raspberry pi : hostapd driver error

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, wifi-driver, hostapd

I'm trying to setup an Access Point on my raspberry pi using hostapd, dnsmasq and two tp link wifi dongles (TL-WN722N 2.0) When I start hostapd, I get this error :

```
nl80211: Driver does not support authentification/association or connect commands 
nl80211 driver initialization failed
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
```

I looked for a solution during several hours but didn't find anything wich worked in my case.

Have someone an idea?

Comment: "I looked for a solution during several hours but didn't find anything wich worked in my case." -- You should tell us your failed attempts,
 otherwise you may get answers that you have already tried.
 Have you seen [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/41238)? There is [this comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41238/nl80211-driver-does-not-support-authentication-association-or-connect-commands#comment63650_43567): "keep in mind that you need good amount of current to power the Pi 2 and a WiFi Adapter." And you have two of them.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I tried another version of hostapd (your link and this one : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=54946) but I got another error : IEEE 802.11: deauthenticated due to local deauth request) while connecting to the AP. My rpi has enough power, and I use a powered USB hub to connect my dongles.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add this relevant information. This is a good practice here. Users who might know the answer read questions, not necessarily all the comments.